# Verifying $\{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$ is a group

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to verify that the set $S = \{0,1, \ldots, n-1\}$ ($n > 1$) is a group under the operation
$$
(a,b) \mapsto \begin{cases}
a + b & \text{ if $a + b \leq n-1$} \\ 
a + b - n & \text{ if $a+b > n - 1$}
\end{cases} 
$$
I know that this is in effect $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, but at this point in the lecture notes I'm working through, equivalence classes have not been introduced, so I need to prove that this set under the given operation is a group. Here is my attempt.

I'm going to denote addition of two elements of $S$ by $+_n$ to distinguish it from addition in $\mathbb{Z}$, denoted $+$.

**Closure.** Given $a,b \in S$, we either have $a + b \leq n-1$ or $a + b > n-1$. If $a + b \leq n-1$, then $a +_{n} b = a + b \in S$. If $a + b > n-1$, then $a +_{n} b = a + b - n$. We need to check that $0 \leq a + b - n \leq n-1$. If $a + b > n - 1$, then $a + b - n > (n-1) - n = -1$. As a sum of integers is another integer, we have $a + b - n \geq 0$. Furthermore, $a,b \in S$, so $a,b \leq n - 1$. Therefore, in $\mathbb{Z}$, $a + b \leq (n-1) + (n-1) = 2n - 2$. Therefore $a + b - n \leq (2n - 2) - n = n - 2 \leq n - 1$. Therefore, $a +_{n} b \in S$.

**Identity.** I claim that $0$ is the identity element in $S$. Fix $a \in S$. Then $0 \leq a \leq n - 1$, so in $\mathbb{Z}$, $0 \leq a + 0 \leq n - 1$, so $a +_{n} 0 = a + 0 = a$. Similarly, as $a + 0 = 0 + a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$, we have $0 +_{n} a = a$.

**Inverses.** Fix $a \in S$. First, $0 + 0 = 0$, so $0$ is its own inverse, so we assume $a > 0$. Then $n - a < n$, i.e., $n - a \leq n - 1$. Further, as $a < n$, $n - a \geq 0$, so $n - a \in S$. Consider $a + _{n} (n-a)$. In $\mathbb{Z}$, we have $a + (n-a) = 0 \leq n - 1$, so we have $a +_{n} (n-a) = 0$. Similarly, $(n-a) +_{n} a = 0$.

The last thing I need to check is associativity. I don't know of a good way to check this other than by cases. If I take $a,b,c \in S$, I need to show that
$$
(a +_{n} b) +_{n} c = a +_{n} (b +_{n} c). 
$$
This produces four cases (considered in $\mathbb{Z}$) for the left-hand side:
\begin{align*}
a + b \leq n - 1, \; (a + b) + c \leq n - 1 \\ 
a + b \leq n - 1, \; (a + b) + c > n - 1 \\ 
a + b > n - 1, \; (a + b - n) + c \leq n - 1 \\ 
a + b > n - 1, \; (a + b - n) + c > n  
\end{align*}
There are similarly four cases for the right-hand side, just swapping $a$ and $b$ with $b$ and $c$ and $c$ with $a$. Therefore, there are $4 \cdot 4 = 16$ cases in total.

I can check all of these manually, but my question is whether this is the way to go. I want to say this result in some way "follows by associativity in $\mathbb{Z}$ (since when I prove the result with equivalence classes, it does) but the operation is completely different here, so that isn't as clear to me.

I'd appreciate if someone could check over my work on closure, identity, and inverses and let me know if I'm on the right track in proving associativity.

Comment: My sympathies. This is a nasty, mostly-pointless exercise, unless its purpose is to convince you that tedious low-level verification is un-enlightening, so that you'll be happy to see a bit of abstraction!?!?! :)  Indeed, saying that $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ inherits all the good features of $mathbb Z$ is the sane response to this... but, yes, this depends on understanding what a "ring quotient map" or "group quotient map" is...

Comment: If you unfold the $\mathbb{Z} / n\mathbb{Z}$ argument a bit, it turns out the essential feature is that $a +_n b$ is equal to either $a+b$ or $a+b-n$, and it is the unique one of those in the range $[0, n)$.  Then, you can use that to prove that both $(a +_n b) +_n c$ and $a +_n (b +_n c)$ are equal to either $a+b+c$, $a+b+c-n$, or $a+b+c-2n$, and also are both in the range $[0, n)$; and it just remains to show that that implies the two are equal.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it in this way: Suppose you have a group $(G, \cdot)$ and an invertible map
$f: G \to S$. Then this map induces a group operation on $S$ given by the group operation of $G$. That is, you can define in $S$

$a \ast b = f(f^{-1}(a)\cdot f^{-1}(b))$

$\ast$ is a group operation because $\cdot$ is.

Now, if you show that $+_n = \ast$, then you are done.

Can you think of any group $(G, \cdot)$ for which it would be easy to do this check?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are saying that $S$ is a group because $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is a group. But that is just what this exercise is trying to prove! Am I missing something?

Comment: He says that he cannot use $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ because they have not done equivalence relations, but another group can be used.

Comment: I think I see now what you have in mind.